# How to aggregate 3 columns in DataFrame to have count and distribution of values in separated columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregation

I have Pandas DataFrame like below:

data types:

- ID - int
- TIME - int
- TG - int

  | ID | TIME | TG |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 111 | 20210101 | 0 |
  | 111 | 20210201 | 0 |
  | 111 | 20210301 | 1 |
  | 222 | 20210101 | 0 |
  | 222 | 20210201 | 1 |
  | 333 | 20210201 | 1 |

And I need to aggregate above DataFrame so as to know:

1. how many IDs are per each value in TIME
2. how many "1" from TG are per each value in TIME
3. how many "0" from TG are per each value in TIME

So I need to something like below:

```
TIME     | num_ID | num_1 | num_0
---------|--------|-------|--------
20210101 | 2      | 0     | 2
20210201 | 3      | 2     | 1
20210301 | 1      | 1     | 0
```

How can I do that in Python Padas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for counts `TIME` values with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for count number of `0` and `1` values:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('TIME').size().to_frame('num_ID')
         .join(pd.crosstab(df['TIME'], df['TG']).add_prefix('num_'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
       TIME  num_ID  num_0  num_1
0  20210101       2      2      0
1  20210201       3      1      2
2  20210301       1      0      1
```

Another idea if need count only `0` and `1` values in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(num_0 = df['TG'].eq(0),
                num_1 = df['TG'].eq(1))
        .groupby('TIME').agg(num_ID = ('TG','size'),
                             num_1=('num_1','sum'),
                             num_0=('num_0','sum'),
                             )
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df1)
       TIME  num_ID  num_1  num_0
0  20210101       2      0      2
1  20210201       3      2      1
2  20210301       1      1      0
```

Comment: jezrael, it works perfect, thank you ! i gave best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'ID':pd.Series.nunique, 'TG': [lambda x: x.eq(1).sum(), lambda x: x.eq(0).sum()]}
col1 = ['num_id', 'num_1', 'num_0']
df.groupby('TIME').agg(dict1).set_axis(col1, axis=1).reset_index()
```

result:

```
    TIME        num_id  num_1   num_0
0   20210101    2       0       2
1   20210201    3       2       1
2   20210301    1       1       0
```